# Material-ui compile error in react (Module build failed)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to add a Navbar to my react app. Here is the App.js file:

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import home from './pages/home';
import login from './pages/login';
import signup from './pages/signup';

//components
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={home}/>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={login}/>
          <Route exact path="/signup" component={signup}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and my Navbar.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

// MUI stuff
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';



class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppBar>
            <Toolbar>
                <Button color='inherit'>Login</Button>
                <Button color='inherit'>Home</Button>
                <Button color='inherit'>Signup</Button>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    )
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

I receive these errors:

> Compiled with problems:X
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@material-ui/utils/esm/getDisplayName.js
> 51:11-21
>
> export 'ForwardRef' (imported as 'ForwardRef') was not found in
> 'react-is' (module has no exports)
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@material-ui/utils/esm/getDisplayName.js
> 54:11-15
>
> export 'Memo' (imported as 'Memo') was not found in 'react-is' (module
> has no exports)
>
> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/react-router/node_modules/mini-create-react-context/dist/esm/index.js
>
> Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js): Error: ENOENT: no such
> file or directory, open
> 'C:\Users---\node_modules\react-router\node_modules\mini-create-react-context\dist\esm\index.js'
>
> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/react-router/node_modules/path-to-regexp/index.js
>
> Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js): Error: ENOENT: no such
> file or directory, open
> 'C:\Users----\node_modules\react-router\node_modules\path-to-regexp\index.js'

I installed material UI with this command:

> yarn add @material-ui/core

package.json:

```
{
  "name": X,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.2",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also include your package.json

Comment: @AndrewTran sure. Added to the question.